# Code coverage :calabash test with Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, calabash, calabash-ios

Can we use Sonarqube for code coverage with calabash test?

If not, which tool can be used for code coverage with calabash test ?

Comment: I never tried before, but you can refer to this question for what people have tried before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105337/code-coverage-for-android-calabash-android-bdd

Answer (score 2):

You can find [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/D1---CI,-Jenkins,-Code-Coverage) some tips at least for iOS dev. There are also some tips for the CI Setup with Calabash

Next to some confs in XCode it is basically this script
Copied from the page

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex
DERIVED_DATA_DIRECTORY=`cut -d "=" -f 2 cucumber.yml | sed 's:/Build/Products/Test-iphonesimulator/YOURAPP.app::'`
OBJECT_DIRECTORY=$DERIVED_DATA_DIRECTORY/Build/Intermediates/YOURAPP.build/Test-iphonesimulator/YOURAPP.build/Objects-normal/i386
gcovr/gcovr -r $PWD/../.. -e Libs/* $OBJECT_DIRECTORY
```

Comment: its for xcode apps but i am looking for xamarin based ios apps.